# Html details element dropdown menu not overlapping everything

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with dropdown menu not overlapping with main body section. It goes under it. I played around with css positioning and zindex values but still no luck. Here is the link for my codepen https://codepen.io/asgg2/pen/zYWbxGO

Here is html:

```
<nav class="subnav">
    <div class="subnav-wrapper">
        <ul class="subnav-items">
            <li>nav 1</li>
            <li>nav 2</li>

        </ul>

        <details class="subnav-paddle">
            <summary></summary>
            <div class="dropdown-men">
                <ul>
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </details>
    </div>

</nav>
<main class="main">
    <h1>hi</h1>
</main>
```

Here is css:

```
.subnav {
    height: 116px;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: hsl(0deg 0% 0%);
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.subnav-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.subnav-items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* overflow-x: auto; */
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: auto;
}

.subnav-paddle {
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.8;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    background-color: black;
    border-left: 1px solid #d2d2d7;
    border-radius: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #f5f5f7;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 33px;
    right: 0;
    padding-top: 28px;
    padding-left: 4px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 100%; */
    z-index: 2;
    width: 160px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #06c;
    border: 1px solid greenyellow;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: #d2d2d7;
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}
```

My real design looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/p78cQ.jpg

Please save me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first your parent nav class have a limited height, then the wrapper underneath of it which is the subnav- wrapper are positioned relative, so your child element will folow the parent element no matter how z-index you have. so positioning your wrapper on absolute position is the answer I came up since your nav have a designated height. Play with the code below for you working sample. Let me know.

```css
 * {
        background-color: gray;
    }


    .subnav {
        height:116px;
        padding: 8px;
        background-color: hsl(0deg 0% 0%);
        color: white;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
    }

    .subnav-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        width:90vw;
       
    }

    .subnav-items {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        list-style: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
        /* overflow-x: auto; */
        overflow: auto;
        width: auto;
        z-index:3;
    }

    .subnav-paddle {
        font-size: 17px;
        line-height: 1.8;
        font-weight: 300;
        letter-spacing: 0em;
        background-color: black;
        border-left: 1px solid #d2d2d7;
        border-radius: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        color: #f5f5f7;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 1;
        width: 33px;
        right: 0;
        padding-top: 28px;
        padding-left: 4px;
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
        position: absolute;
        /* top: 100%; */
        z-index: 2;
        width: 160px;
        padding-top: 4px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        margin-top: 2px;
        list-style: none;
        background-color: #06c;
        border: 1px solid greenyellow;
        border-radius: 6px;
        box-shadow: #d2d2d7;
        right: 50px;
        left: auto;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="subnav">
        <div class="subnav-wrapper">
            <ul class="subnav-items">
                <li>nav 1</li>
                <li>nav 2</li>

            </ul>

            <details class="subnav-paddle">
                <summary></summary>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </details>
       

    </nav>
    <main class="main">
        <h1>hi</h1>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for putting me on the right track! The problem was the parent positioning so I played around a bit in the browser and got the desired result.

Comment: thats good that you got the idea. I'm glad it help you get on track, Please accept this answer so your quetion are answered by clicking the check on the left side. Happy Coding..

Comment: Ohh! This's my first time using Stackoverflow so I don't know how to use it. Thanks again kind stranger!